# Access MPI_User_function from underlying MPI_Op handle

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I want to write my own scan function in MPI style which means i have to access the associative operation from MPI_Op parameter. I can't really find the definition of the MPI_Op struct and therefore don't know what offset is used to access the function. I want to do this this way because i also want to handle user defined functions which are created and bound to handles with MPI_Op_Create function and also be as close as possible to the MPI implementation of MPI_Scan.
I tried the following snippet so far, supposing the address of the function is saved without offset in e.g. MPI_SUM handle:

```
int asize = 10;
int inArray[asize];
int outArray[asize];

for(int i = 0; i < asize; i++) {
   inArray[i] = i;
   inOutArray[i] = i;
}

MPI_User_function *f = (MPI_User_function*) MPI_SUM;
MPI_Datatype type = MPI_INT;

f(inArray, inOutArray, &asize, &type);
```

This code is not working for me, i mostly get segementation faults with "Signal code: Invalid permissions". It would not be tragic if i can't access the predefined operations like MPI_SUM, MPI_MAX,... (i could just write the functionality myself), but i want at least access user defined functions. I am not enirely sure if what i want to do is even possible, does someone have any insights?

Comment: did you google `MPI_User_function` and `MPI_Op_create` ? please post a [mcve] if you are still stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MPI_Op` is an MPI handle - it is an opaque value that could be a pointer to a structure, or an integer index in a table, or a magic value. But the point is, it doesn't really matter since you are not supposed to know what exactly it is (therefore "opaque").

Instead of breaching the API barrier by examining internal MPI structure, you should use [`MPI_Reduce_local`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.0/man3/MPI_Reduce_local.3.php), which is the portable version of extracting the reduction function from the operation and calling it with the two arrays.

Your code should read:

```c
int asize = 10;
int inArray[asize];
int outArray[asize];

for(int i = 0; i < asize; i++) {
   inArray[i] = i;
   inOutArray[i] = i;
}

MPI_Reduce_local(inArray, inOutArray, asize, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM);
```

The function works with both predefined reduction operations (such as `MPI_SUM`) and user-defined ones.

When implementing global reductions, you need to pay special attention to operation commutativity, especially when dealing with user-defined operations. Make [`MPI_Op_commutative`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.0/man3/MPI_Op_commutative.3.php) your other best friend and do not perform out of order (sub-)reductions when the operation is not commutative.

Both functions are described in Section 5.9.7 (pg. 189) of the [MPI standard](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf).

Comment: Wow seems like i was thinking way too complicated, that is all i wanted, ty very much!